# Can I Send a Message Request Directly to a Queue?

Tags: java, queue, jms

I have a client that receives messages from a Queue. I currently have a `MessageListener` that implements `onMessage()`.

Once the message is received, it is processed further then saved to a Database on the `onMessage()` method; the client then acknowledges the message receipt.

As long as the database is up there is no problem. But if the DB is down, the client will not acknowledge.

To cater for this, I want the client to be sending scheduled requests to the queue for any unacknowledged messages at scheduled intervals.

As it is, the only way I have of doing this is to restart the client which is not Ideal. Is there a way to trigger the queue to resend an unacknowledged message without a restart?

What i have in `onMessage()`:

```
//code to connect to  queue
try {
if (DB is available){
        //process message
        //save required details to DB
        msg.acknowledge();
    }
    else{
        //schedule to request same message later from queue
    }
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: If the Database is down, why not wait until it is up before attempting to proceed.  That way there is no need to replay the messages

Comment: You mean block until DB is up? I am not sure this is ok ... unless I misunderstand your comment.

Comment: What would happen if you blocked until the database is up? Does that thread have something more important to do? ;) If it does, I would have that more important thing run in another thread, session or connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I have stumbled on the session.recover() which I can use to trigger redelivery. I have seen there is the RedeliveryPolicy class which I can use to set message resend  options. Now my code looks like:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
RedeliveryPolicy policy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
policy.setBackOffMultiplier((short) 2);
policy.setRedeliveryDelay(30000);
policy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(60000);
policy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
((ActiveMQConnectionFactory)factory).setRedeliveryPolicy(policy);

final Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
...
...
...
..


//inside onMessage()
try {
    if (DB is available){
        //process message
        //save required details to DB
        msg.acknowledge();
    }
    else{
        session.recover();
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard behavior is already doing what you want: if the message broker is using the same database and the database is not available, it will not accept the messages and thus the client will spool them until the message broker is ready again.

If they do not share the same database and the message broker is on, it will spool the message and retry if `onMessage` throws an exception.
The message broker will try to resend according to its configurable policy.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my problem then is how and where to configure activeMQ to resend unacknowledged messages instead of initialing resend request from the client. How can I do this?